# Variable substitution in bash printf {}

Tags: bash

I am trying to print true 10 times using a var and its not working

```
count=10
printf 'true\n%.0s' {1..$count}
```

This works:

```
printf 'true\n%.0s' {1..10}
```

I understand that `{}` are evaluated before vars but I cannot get around it.

Comment: See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.7B1...24n.7D

Answer (score -2, accepted):

read http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-iterate-over-a-variable-range-of-numbers-in-bash/

the way to fix this to work is:

```
printf 'true\n%.0s' $(eval echo "{1..$count}")
```

Comment: There's no reason for a subshell here; it only adds inefficiency. If you want to use eval (and see my discussion in @anubhava's response as to the security impact of that), better to do it in the immediate shell.

Comment: To quote from a comment in that discussion, in case it disappears with the answer's retraction: I wouldn't want to be responsible if someone throws an `eval` or a `bash -c` around code which is expanding `"$filename"`... when they get a file named `/tmp/$(rm -rf /)/hello`.

Answer (score 13):

That's not a problem with `printf`, it's a problem with `{1..$count}`. That expansion can only be done with constants.

```
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do
  printf 'true\n%.0s' "$i"
done
```

...or, if you really want to expand onto a single command line, collect your arguments into an array first:

```
arr=()
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do arr+=( "$i" ); done
printf 'true\n%.0s' "${arr[@]}"
```

To explain why: Brace expansion (`{1..10}`) happens **before** parameter expansion (`$count`). Thus, by the time `$count` is expanded to `10`, no more brace expansion is going to occur.

Comment: This is definitely the safe approach +1

Comment: Sorry I was probably not clear ..I knew the ways of using for loop solns but was looking for a way to avoid that ..by using something like an eval ..

Comment: @user3348409 Don't sacrifice safety for conciseness. Use a loop.

Answer (score 4):

The other way (using an external process):

```
printf 'true\n%.0s' $(seq $count)
```

Comment: `seq` is neither POSIX-specified nor a bash built-in, and is not available on all operating systems where bash is supported. That said, it's better to eat the overhead of a subprocess and take a portability hit than to use 'eval', so this is an improvement on the accepted answer; +1.

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it, here's a slightly bizarre way:

```
mapfile -n $count a < /dev/urandom; printf 'true\n%.0s' ${!a[@]}
```

Comment: [Downvoters gonna downvote](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/haters-gonna-hate), I suppose

Comment: (Oh -- actually, since you're iterating over indexes rather than values, yeah, the content *really* don't matter, so no potential for bugs related to the content read. I can't explain that downvote, then; clearly someone with no sense of humor).